# Reading data from a .csv file to append into a 2D array in c

Tags: c

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <4; i++) {
        while (c != EOF)
            token = strtok((fgets(token,5,fp)), delim);
    }
}
```

Hey everyone, I'm new to C and I was given a project to take a csv file and count the average number of the values in each column. Right now I'm trying to parse the lines by the commas. I found the function [strtok], but I'm definitely implementing it incorrectly. I have the number of rows and columns in the csv file, I just need help figuring out how to parse each line by "," and place those values into a 2D array. Above is my current code that I was going to use to append the values to the array, but I keep getting a "Segmentation fault". Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the whole code for the function. I include stdio.h and stdlib.h:

```
void main() {
    char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
    char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

    char *file_name = "test.txt";

    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    int array[4][4];
    //int array1 [2] = {1, 3};

    int counter = 0;
    char *token = " ";
    const char *delim = (const char *)',';

    char c = fgetc(fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        token = "";
        for (int j = 0; j <4; i++) {
            while (c != EOF)
                token = strtok((fgets(token,5,fp)), delim);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

A sample input would be something like this:

```
10,20,30,60
40,50,60,70
70,80,90,80
100,110,120,70
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input file? Also your whole code would be nice.

Comment: This question needs a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is not clear when `c` would ever become `EOF`.

Comment: @MustacheMoses I have updated the post. Please let me know if you can help!

Comment: I believe @Pablo has given you a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, you are using `strtok` incorrectly.

The first thing I would do is to read each line and the parse the line using
`strtok`, like this:

```
char line[1024];

const char *delim=",\n";

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
    char *token = strtok(line, delim);

    do {
        printf("token: %s\n", token);
    } while(token = strtok(NULL, delim));
}
```

`strtok` requires that all subsequent calls of `strtok` must be called with
`NULL`. `strtok` will return `NULL` when no more token can be found, usually the
end of the line has been reached. Note that I added the newline in the
delimiters argument. When the destination buffer is large enough `fgets` writes
the newline as well. Putting the newline in the delimiters list is nice trick
because `strtok` will get rid of the newline for you.

The code above gives you a way getting each cell of the csv, as a string. You
would have to convert the values yourself. This is the tricky bit, if the csv
contains empty spaces, quotes, etc, you need different strategies to parse the
correct value of the cell. You can use function like `strtol` & friend which
allow you to recover from errors, but they are not bullet proof, there will be
cases when they fail as well.

An easy example would be:

```
char line[1024];

const char *delim=",\n";

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
{
    char *token = strtok(line, delim);

    do {
        int val;
        if(sscanf(token, "%d", &n) != 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "'%s' is not a number!\n", token);
        else
            printf("number found: %d\n", val);
    } while(token = strtok(NULL, delim));
}
```

Note that this not cover all cases, for example cell that are in quotes.

The last thing to be done would be to store the values. One way of doing it is
to allocate memory for a pointer to an `int` array and reallocate memory for
every cell. Here again the problem lies in the csv file, sometimes they have the
wrong format, some rows will be empty or some rows will have more or less
columns than the other rows, this can be tricky. At this point it would be a good
idea to use a library for parsing csv.

The following code will assume that csv is well formatted and the number of
columns is always the same across all rows and no line is longer than 1023
characters long. When `*cols` is 0, I calculate the number of columns base on
the first line. If other rows have less columns, all remaining values will be 0
(because of the `calloc` sets new allocated memory to 0). If there are more
colmuns than in the first row, this columns will be ignored:

```
int **parse_csv(const char *filename, size_t *rows, size_t *cols)
{
    if(filename == NULL || rows == NULL || cols == NULL)
        return NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int **csv = NULL, **tmp;

    *rows = 0;
    *cols = 0;

    char line[1024];
    char *token;
    char *delim = ",\n";

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp))
    {
        tmp = realloc(csv, (*rows + 1) * sizeof *csv);
        if(tmp == NULL)
            return csv; // return all parsed rows so far

        csv = tmp;

        if(*cols == 0)
        {
            // calculating number of rows
            char copy[1024];
            strcpy(copy, line);

            token = strtok(copy, delim);

            do {
                (*cols)++;
            } while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)));
        }

        int *row = calloc(*cols, sizeof *row);

        if(row == NULL)
        {
            if(*rows == 0)
            {
                free(csv);
                return NULL;
            }

            return csv; // return all parsed rows so far
        }

        // increment rows count
        (*rows)++;

        size_t idx = 0;

        token = strtok(line, delim);

        do {
            if(sscanf(token, "%d", row + idx) != 1)
                row[idx] = 0; // in case the conversion fails,
                              // just to make sure to have a defined value
                              // in the cell

            idx++;
        } while((token = strtok(NULL, delim)) && idx < *cols);

        csv[*rows - 1] = row;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return csv;
}

void free_csv(int **csv, size_t rows)
{
    if(csv == NULL)
        return;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        free(csv[i]);

    free(csv);
}
```

Now you can parse it like this:

```
size_t cols, rows;
int **csv = parse_csv("file.csv", &rows, &cols);

if(csv == NULL)
{
    // error handling...
    // do not continue
}

...

free_csv(csv, rows);
```

Now `csv[3][4]` would give you the cell at row 3, col 4 (starting from 0).

---

**edit**

Things I noticed from you code:

`void main()` is wrong. `main` should have only one of the following prototypes:

- `int main(void);`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv);`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`

Another:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
    char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
    ...

}
```

Don't put that in the `main` function, put it outside, also there are standard
header files for this. In this case include `string.h`

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
```

Another

```
const char *delim = (const char *)',';
```

This is just wrong, it's like trying to sell an apple and call it orange. `','`
is a single character of type `char`. It has the value 44. It's the same as
doing:

```
const char *delim = (const char*) 44;
```

you are setting the address where `delim` should point to 44.

You have to use double quotes:

```
const char *delim = ",";
```

Note that `'x'` and `"x"` are not the same. `'x'` is 120 (see [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)), it's
a single char. `"x"` is a string literal, it returns you a pointer to the start
of a sequence of characters that ends with the `'\0'`-terminating byte, aka a
string. Those are fundamentally different things in C.